# Could not change the group owner ( Group Owner Intent )

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I just add two buttons on the **WiFiDirectDemo** provided by Google. One of the button is called "Owner" and the other is "Client".

**I what two device to choose if they what to be the owner or not.**

In the beginning, I thought it would work if I change the number between **0 and 15**:

```
config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
```

But it didn't work.

**One of the device keeping act as Group Owner.** Even if I change the "groupOwnerIntent".

Here is my code ( DeviceDetailFragment.java ):

```
mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_owner).setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    intentNumber = 15;
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),String.valueOf(intentNumber), 
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_client).setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    intentNumber = 0;
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), String.valueOf(intentNumber), 
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

//********************************************************************

    mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect)
                          .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //WifiP2pConfig config = chooseOwner(ownerIntentNumber);
        WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
    config.groupOwnerIntent = intentNumber;
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), String.valueOf(intentNumber), 
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }   
});
```

Please give me some advise. Thank you very much.

My devices are two Nexus 7.

Answer (score 1):

I just suffered with same problem.

In my case, that happened because `Wi-Fi Direct` group was remembered by the device.

In Galaxy Nexus, I could forget it by changing setting in

`Setting` -> `Wi-Fi` -> `Wi-Fi Direct` -> Select the group remembered -> `Forget`

And then, I could change the group owner as I configured.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was solved. After press OK to forget this group it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another common mistake I made:
The the device on which the Owner/Client button is pressed (to change the config groupownerintent value) must initiate the connection by pressing the connect button and **not the other device**.